# Consolidating variables into unified time series

Tags: r, time-series

My data is organized the following way:

```
product  week1  ...   week52   year    release
A        NA     ...   100      2008    2008-06-06
B        200    ...   200      2008    2008-01-01 
...      ...    ...   ...      ...     ...
A        60     ...   50       2009    2008-06-06
```

where `product` refers to product identifiers, `week1` to `week52` are weekly sales over the year, `year` is the current year, and `release` is the release date of the product.

I would like to combine and "pivot" year and weeks to create a new dataset like this one:

```
product  date        released  sales
A        2008-01-07  0         NA       
...      ...         ...       ...
A        2008-12-31  1         100
A        2009-01-07  1         60
...      ...         ...       ...
A        2009-12-31  1         50
B        2008-01-07  1         200
...      ...         ...       ...
B        2008-12-31  1         200
```

where now instead of `week_i` and `year` we have a single time series variable for each product, and `released` is a dummy for whether the product has been released at any point in time.

My question is: how can I do that in a computationally efficient way considering that I have tens of thousands of products over multiple years in the data? Don't bother about actual calendar years being longer than 52 weeks, simply consider that the last week of the year is made longer to absorb the remaining days.

I could create a new panel data frame with product id's and the required times series to the left, and then write a three-level loop that would go through all products, all years and all weeks in turn. For instance, here is the idea of the inner-most loop to get `sales`, with data frames `olddata` and `newdata`, and assuming the two outer loops currently point to product `P` and year `Y`:

```
temp=newdata[which(newdata$product==P & year(newdata$date)==Y),]
for (i in (1:52)) {
 temp[i,4]=olddata[which(olddata$product==P & olddata$year==Y),1+i]
}
```

where `lubridate` provides year extraction.

This, however, would probably be very inefficient to compute trough.
Do you have a more straightforward suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: here is some code to generate a sample organized like the data I can't share:

```
mydata=matrix(0,4,55)
colnames(mydata)=c("product",paste0(rep("week",52),seq(from=1,to=52)),"year","release")
mydata[1,1]="A"
mydata[2,1]="B"
mydata[3,1]="A"
mydata[4,1]="B"
mydata[1,54]=2008
mydata[2,54]=2008
mydata[3,54]=2009
mydata[4,54]=2009
library(lubridate)
mydata[1,55]=ymd("2008-06-06")
mydata[2,55]=ymd("2008-01-01")
mydata[3,55]=ymd("2008-06-06")
mydata[4,55]=ymd("2008-01-01")
mydata[1,2:23]=rep(NA,22)
mydata[1,24:53]=seq(from=71,by=1,length.out = 30)
mydata[2,2:53]=rep(200,52)
mydata[3,2:53]=seq(from=60,to=50,length.out = 52)
mydata[4,2:53]=rnorm(52,200,20)
mydata=as.data.frame(mydata)
```

Comment: Since you're not just pivoting cleanly on `release` or `date`, I suggest you will need to put some more substantial sample data, and please make it easily copyable using something like `dput(head(x,n=20))`. Ensure that the sample data shows enough variability in it; might not take much, but only you will know.

Comment: I've edited the OP, adding code to generate some data.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is the most simple way I've found to do that. It still requires a loop, though; slow but not too cumbersome to type.

First sort the data by product id:

```
mydata=mydata[order(mydata$product, mydata$year),]

product  week1  ...   week52   year    release
A        NA     ...   100      2008    2008-06-06
A        60     ...   50       2009    2008-06-06
B        200    ...   200      2008    2008-01-01
```

Then notice that by transposing the matrix of weekly sales data you get (showing the observations for product A):

```
t(mydata[which(mydata$product=="A"),2:53])

week1  NA   60
...    ...  ...
week52 100  50
```

Where the first column corresponds to 2008 and the second one to 2009.
Thus, by vectorizing this matrix you get a column of weekly data:

```
c(t(mydata[which(mydata$product=="A"),2:53]))

week1   NA
...     ... 
week52  100
week1   60
...     ...
week52  50
```

Which is what we want to obtain for every product. The resulting loop is, denoting `newdata` the "stacked up" data frame:

```
# List all unique products
products=unique(mydata$product)
N=length(products)
for (i in (1:N)) {
 # Replace values in the vector of "stacked up" sales:
 newdata$sales[which(newdata$product==products[i])]=c(t(mydata[which(mydata$product==products[i]),2:53]))
}
```

This loop takes a while to run but doesn't require too much user arithmetics with increments, so the risk of human mistakes isn't that high.